# sed command to replace wildcard string with contents of a file containing javascript

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I've worked up to the following:

```
routes=`cat "$dir"/file.js`
perl -pi -w -e 's/return\[\[\{path:.*\}\]\]/'"$routes"'/g;' "$dir"dist/main*bundle.js
```

The goal is:

1. read some lines of js from a file and save that to variable routes (working)
2. find a wildcarded string `return[[{path:` * `}]]` in js file (working)
3. replace that string with the content of variable $routes (failing)

Right now, I'm getting errors:

```
Unquoted string "window" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 2.
Unquoted string "template" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 2.
Unquoted string "path" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 6.
Regexp modifiers "/d" and "/u" are mutually exclusive at -e line 1, at end of line
Regexp modifiers "/d" and "/l" are mutually exclusive at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, near "; let routeMap "
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Which seems like perl isn't dropping the contents of the variable into the replacement, and is instead trying to interpret the contents as more commands.

The contents of the file is more or less:

```
return (() => {
  let template = window.CONFIG.template;

  let routeMap = {
    foo: [[{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: 'app/modules/foo/foo.module#fooModule'
    }]]
  }

  return routeMap[template];
})();
```

The variable contains javascript which requires some level of conflicting syntax. How can I correct this so that a direct replacement is made with the exact content of the variable without conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding your string in a variable and then replace it with printf in a file by file basis

```
routes=`cat "$dir"/file.js`
stack=$(perl -p -w -e 's/return\[\[\{path:.*\}\]\]/%s/g;' "$dir"dist/some_bundle.js)
printf "$stack" "$route" > "$dir"dist/some_bundle.js
```

Comment: Cool idea–requires removal of -i flag to work (changes file inline, rather than outputting result), but otherwise putting the simple string `%s` in place of the found regex, then replacing with code afterwards with printf is a working solution. Appreciated!

Comment: welcome! edited the answer as suggested. Let me know if it's not correct.